# Identify all types of repetitions in the given string of text

Tags: java, search, pattern-matching

I am solving a problem to identify repetitions over the stroke data and I have converted those stroke data into text as follows (not exact).

```
a1 a b c b1 x y z c1 b c c2 a b c a2 x y b2 w c3 x y z
```

I need to identify all repetitive patterns of size `>=2` in the above string. For suppose `x y`, `b c`, `a b c`, `x y z` need to be identified along with their respective positions. How can i find it out using the brute force approach in Java (even though its weird)

Comment: Ideally we'd look for some code you've tried and experienced a problem with

Comment: Well there is a lot of solutions. How about splitting up the data into the single patterns, storing the pattern plus original position and then iterating over all patterns and storing them in a map (mapping pattern to number of occurances)

Comment: I think you'll need something like this for the solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Comment: For now i requires a brute force solution?

Answer (score 1):

For all lengths >= 2 iterate over the string and substring all contained possible substrings of that length. Store them and find duplicates in each Set of results for those lengths.

To also find the positions just remember them along with the substrings.